# Trouble getting App Script to read data in multiple ranges

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to get App Script to read a ranges of cells from different sheets in a workbook, but I keep getting "Range not found (line 30). I have a bit of experience with Javascript, but App Script is fairly new to me, so some tips and where to find good documentation or tutorials would really help as well.

```
function getvalues(values2) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(values2)
  var raw_values = []
  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
    raw_values.push(sheet[i])
  }
  return raw_values
}
```

Edit

Here is what the value2 is. They're ranges separated by commas, and each range is from a different sheet in the workbook.

```
January!W22:W35,February!W22:W35,March!W22:W35,April!W22:W35,May!W22:W35,June!W22:W35,July!W22:W35,August!W22:W35,September!W22:W35,October!W22:W35,November!W22:W35,December!W22:W35
```

Comment: What does `values2` contain when you get this error?     Apps-script docs for google sheets are [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Comment: It contains comma separated ranges, each one from a different sheet in the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, getRange() doesn't seem to specify a comma separated list of ranges as a valid argument. The error is most likely because the function is trying to interpret the entire string as a single range.
You may need to retrieve each range separately and then aggregate them in some way.

I've included an example of how you might do this.

```
let myRanges = "January!W22:W35,February!W22:W35,March!W22:W35"
function getvalues(values2) {
  let raw_values = []
  values2.split(",").forEach(a1range => {
    let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(a1range)
    console.log(range.getValues())
    // get the values from the range and push them to raw_values
  })
  
  return raw_values
}
getvalues(myRanges)
```

Additionally, it looks like getRange() will return a Range object, which doesn't directly contain the values from the range, but has the methods getValue() and getValues() to return the values from the selected cells. getValues appears to return a multidimensional array representing the rows/columns from your range, so you'll need to do some extra processing depending on how you need your data formatted.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

Considering that, it would probably also be a good idea to change the function name to something other than getvalues to avoid confusion.